# Removing the preview added table row dynamically

Tags: jquery

I have a table with few rows and I'm adding to each row the onclick Eventhanlder which creating a new TR as next element:

```
$(this).after('<tr><td></td><td colspan="8">' 
                       + $(this)
                       .find('td:eq(1)')
                       .text() + '</td></tr>');
```

This workng fine.

But I would like to remove the TR I just created by clicking on the next TR (in this case it's the third TR).

I need something like: $(this).before('tr').remove() ;-)

Could u pls. help?

Cheers
Amin

Comment: Please post a complete code example and if possible a jsFiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick

```
$(this).prev().remove();
```

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Hello 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Hello 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Hello 3</td>
    </tr>    
</table>
```

**JS**

```
$('tr').on('click', function(){
    $(this).prev().remove();
})
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/dPcXv/)

Comment: Great! that's it: $(this).prev().remove();
Many Thx!

Answer (score 0):

See documentation here:http://api.jquery.com/remove/ and here: http://api.jquery.com/before/

Comment: Thx, but it doesn't help cause I would like to remove the previews TR wich has been added dynamically without Class, Id or Contains etc.